# Force text wrap using CSS on Mobile

Tags: css, word-wrap

I want the green strip at the top of [this page](https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?page_id=117) to resize vertically (text-wrapping) on a mobile so the whole message is displayed.

I've researched the relevant CSS and tried `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and 
`word-wrap: break-word;`

but no luck.

Please help - CSS makes me want to cry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `white-space: normal;` to the `md-trigger` div. That div has the `btn` class which is setting `white-space: nowrap;`, and that is causing the issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's great. Thanks. I don't suppose you also know how I could make the modal fully vertically scrollable? currently it only scrolls after clicking "Start Quiz" and the "close me" button is sometimes off-screen at the bottom on mobile.

Comment: Your modal has the class `md-content_2160`, which sets the height at 525px. You need to either reduce the content/space within the modal, or make the modal bigger, if you want to avoid a scrollbar.